# How to get actual image width and height after load in colorbox plugin?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I open a MVC view in colorbox. That view loads an image on which I let user add annotations. Before my annotation plugin works and render the canvas, I need to
know the width and height of the image loaded. This sets the canvas dimension.

I am able to get the image width and height just fine in FF, Chrome, Opera.
But in IE8, I always get image width and height as 0

Is there anyone who can help me with getting the image dimension once
the image is loaded?

Here is how I call colorbox to open my MVC view:

```
<a href="site/photos/album/1234" class="notes colorbox"></a>
```

This is the view:

```
<div id="dvImg">
    <img id="imgAnnotate" src="path/abc.jpg" />
</div>

$(function () {
    $("#imgAnnotate").load(function () {
        Width = this.width;
        Height = this.height;
        alert('W=' + Width + ' H=' + Height); <-- IE shows as W=0 H=0
    });
});
```

I also tried a imagesLoaded plugin but doesn't work on colorbox:

```
$(function () {
    var $dvImg = $('#dvImg');
    function loopImages($images) {
        $images.each(function () {
            alert('h6=' + $(this).height() + ' w6=' + $(this).width()); //FF says 0
            alert('h7=' + this.height + ' w7=' + this.width); //FF OK!!! not IE
        });
    }

    $dvImg.imagesLoaded(function ($images) {
        loopImages($images);
    });
});
```

Another point: `$(window).load()` in the view is not firing at all. May be because it
is loaded in colorbox?

Anyway, this seems very very tough to do!!

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine for me in IE. Check this fiddle (in IE): http://jsfiddle.net/gERZe/

Comment: The code has to work with COLORBOX jquery plugin.

Comment: techfoobar: is it possible for you to try this with colorbox plugin and see if your code still behaves the same? Just load same image inside colorbox popup. Thanks a lot.

Comment: sure. i'll try it out with colorbox and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var Width = $(this).css("width");
var Height = $(this).css("height");
```

Comment: How is this different from $(this).width() and $(this).height()?

Comment: it reads the actual css maybee its working this way ? its just a suggestion that you could try :)

both do the same in a different way... should be the same result... I would try both maybee this solves your problem...

regards